# Mathematica Presentation Cell Formatting

Tags: formatting, slideshows

In one of the *Mathematica* (v9) slide templates, they have an example cell that looks like this:

[image]

Where there is a "SideCaption" that appears to be the *Mathematica*-equivalent of a text box to the right of the image. I can't for the life of me figure out how this is replicate this other than copying the cell and pasting elsewhere.

I did find this code looking at the notebook file however:

```
Cell["SideCaption How do I get this?", "SideCaption"]
```

Is this something I can generate programmatically, or something that needs to be copied when used elsewhere? I could see this format being used in more places than presentations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[BoxData[
   TagBox[GridBox[{{ToBoxes[Graphics[Circle[]]], 
       Cell["Text", "SideCaption"]}}], "Grid"]], "SideCaptionArray"]
```

SideCaption and SideCaptionArray are in the Default.nb style sheet if you want to change them.

Comment: Nice! I did not know about `"SideCaption"` and `"SideCaptionArray"` (edit: I now see that the OP had also mentioned it)

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeet.

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica 10.3 we now have `TextGrid`:

```
TextGrid[{{Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"], "SideCaption How do I get this?"}}]
```

[image]

and you can edit the text in the output just like in the presentation template.